# "invalid number" error

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g

On executing:

```
select * 
from emp 
where to_char(hiredate ,'yy')='13';
```

This query, which is in oracle10g, is giving an error as "invalid number" pointing at hiredate.

My table description is:

```
NO         NUMBER(10)
NAME       VARCHAR2(15)
JOB        VARCHAR2(10)
COMPANY    VARCHAR2(15)
SALARY     NUMBER(10)
DEPTNO     NUMBER(5)
HIREDATE   VARCHAR2(15)
```

Comment: can you give example, what kind of date format is stored in `HIREDATE` as `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 2):

The column `HIREDATE` is already a character string, not a date.  You don't want to use `to_char()` on it.

Instead, you want to use a string function, but that depends on the format.  Something like:

```
where HIREDATE like '%13'
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change `HIREDATE` to type `DATE` and use your SQL statement, it should work fine. That way you'll be able to use `HIREDATE` for some other purposes that requires the datatype to be `DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `Date Data Type` you must convert your `HIREDATE` Column to `Date` from `VARCHAR2`. So You can try this Solution.

Assuming you have data in `HIREDATE` as `28-02-2013`, the Query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE To_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIREDATE,'dd-MM-YY'),'YY')='13';
```

`'dd-MM-YY'` depends on your `HIREDATE` data,

So, here you must have to use `To_DATE` function to convert your column first before extracting `Year` from it *(if you don't want to use `` `where HIREDATE like '%13' `` as suggested before by `@Gordon Linoff`)*.

Answer (score 0):

HIREDATE is VARCHAR2 whereas to_char(xxx, 'yy') is expecting a date or timestamp data type

Answer (score 0):

select * 
from emp 
where to_char(to_date(hiredate,'DD/MM/YYYY') ,'yy')='13';